# Difference between gcc warnings and gcc error messages

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gcc-warning

I was compiling this code snippet in code-blocks without any messages at all:

```
printf("adress of x %i\n",ptr);
```

Now I try to compile this via terminal and gcc but I get this message:

```
warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ [-Wformat=]
```

gcc produces a executable anyway (it runs). What did I do wrong?

Comment: Always use %p for pointers.

Comment: Warning = you are doing something wrong, but not something that will prevent me to compile, Error = you are doing something certainly wrong (if your parametere is type `int**`, that pass as parameter `**ptr`)

Comment: Warnings are when a knowledgeable user might be doing something OK, but a learner not likely.  Error is when code is delectably wrong.

Comment: Format `%i` is for integers, `%p` is for pointers. It is possible that the size of the pointer is the same as an integer on some platforms, but this is definitely not guaranteed. Function `printf` will read from memory the number of bytes indicated by the format specifier and render the data  accordingly as an integer, but strange things can happen if pointer size is different that `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

A warning is "don't touch the plate; it's hot".

An error is "you touched the plate, it was *really* hot, and now you have no fingers".

---

A warning is the compiler telling you that you could do something better, but that it can continue for now. An error is irrecoverable: you *need* to fix the stated problem in order to get a successful compilation.

Note that it's generally advised that you treat warnings as seriously as errors, for the sake of good, safe code. For example, the warning you're getting today is telling you that your `printf` or `scanf` format string appears to be wrong which, while not a compilation error, is likely to result in a crash (or worse, subtle weird bugs) at runtime.

---

The format specifier `%p` is for pointers.

Comment: Minor point: I would avoid the "we ...". Either say "I ...", or explicitly say whom you're speaking for. Even "the consensus is ..." is fine.

Comment: @cigien It's generally accepted across the C++ community, is it not? Happy to change the wording if you disagree with that, but I don't think I've heard dissent on this point for 15 or 20 years

Comment: No, there's no dissent, there's just something about the wording that makes me uncomfortable :) I've made the edit I'd like, if you want to rollback that's fine, it's not a big deal.